# TextInputLayout error text not displaying as intended after keyboard is shown and dismissed

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using TextInputLayout to take advantage of the floating hint and error display, the validation logic triggers when I press the continue button, it works fine if I don't select any textInput, the error is displayed correctly, but if I select a textInput, dismiss the keyboard and then press the continue button, the textInput is highlited in red as expected but the error text is not displayed.

What seems to be weird is that I tried the same code, same layout on a Acitvity and it worked fine (I am using a Fragment for this), but I would much rather stick to Fragment.

I also inspected the layout (when the error was not displayed) and the error textView seems to be there (in the view tree you can see the textView inside the TextInputLayout with a width of 0 and the text set to whatever I set it to)

My layout is:

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_acc_details"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_details"
            android:textAppearance="@style/headerText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_acc_details"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_acc_details">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_name"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/sign_up_text_name"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColour"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_last_name"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:errorEnabled="true">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_last_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/sign_up_text_last_name"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColour"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_email1"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:errorEnabled="true">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_email1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/sign_up_text_email1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColour"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_email2"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/text_email2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/sign_up_text_email2"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColour"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button_sign_up_continue"
            style="@style/PrimaryButton"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_button_continue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My Fragment code:

```
class SignUpFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_up, container, false)
        return  rootView     
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        button_sign_up_continue.setOnClickListener {
            validateText()
        }
    }

    private fun validateText() {
        if (text_name.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            text_input_name.error = resources.getText(R.string.sign_up_error_text)
        } else {
            text_input_name.error = null
        }
        if (text_last_name.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            text_input_last_name.error = resources.getText(R.string.sign_up_error_text)
        } else {
            text_input_last_name.error = null
        }
        val isValidEmail = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.toRegex().matches(text_email1.text.toString())
        if (text_email1.text.isNullOrEmpty() || !isValidEmail) {
            text_input_email1.error = resources.getText(R.string.sign_up_invalid_email)
        } else {
            text_input_email1.error = null
        }
    }
```

The gif shows how by tapping the button first works fine, but if I select a textInput first and then tap the button the error text is not displayed (it is set and is there by checking in the layout inspector tool but the width is 0 for some reason)

[image]

Comment: Show your activity code also!

Comment: sorry forgot that, is not much, but I added it :)

Comment: Check my updated answer!

Answer (score 1):

After spending quite a lot of time in this issue, I found out that this seems to be a Material Android issue (at least on com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0 library version), you can find the issue tracker here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136435162

For the time being I found a work around to fix the errorTextView's width issue by creating a TextInputLayout extension and updating the errorTextView width manually:

```
    val errorTextView = this.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textinput_error)
    var params = errorTextView?.layoutParams
    params?.width = yourWidth
    errorTextView?.layoutParams = params
```

It is not pretty but it does the trick for now, hope it helps someone

Comment: This solution didn't work on 1.1.0 :(
I've  tried to set width for the errorTextView, it's parent and it still disappears.
I doubt TextInputLayout drawing method has imposed some width/height calculation causing this weird error...

Answer (score 0):

> Put this method inside onActivityCreated() instead of onStart()

```
button_sign_up_continue.setOnClickListener {
      validateText()
}
```

Comment: no that did not fix it. I don't think the issue has to do with that because it works just fine without selecting any textInputLayout, I only get empty error text if the keyboard displays and hides before validating errors

Comment: No beacause you are setting error as  text_input_email1.error = null

Comment: yes I did try it, like I said, it is not working and I believe that is not reason

Comment: That will cause a crash because button_sign_up_continue is not ready to be access yet

Comment: Then use onActivityCreated() and check my updated answer